# ViewResult exists both in "System.Web.Mvc.dll" and "System.Web.Mvc.dll"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, controller, gac

I am writing a unit test for a controller method in my MVC4 project.

And as a part of - Act - phase I am :-

```
var result  = controller.SomeMethod(SomeViewModel) as ViewResult;
```

when I get the error - ViewResult exists both in "System.Web.Mvc.dll" and "System.Web.Mvc.dll".

In my project solution I do have a single reference to this assembly.
I do have 2 different versions in the GAC.

What should the course of action be for fixing this one?

Comment: In your web.config file do you have multiple references to the MVC library?

Comment: @kadumel Yes. I removed one of them but still the issue exists.

Comment: Can you post your Web.Config file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test project had MVC 4.0 referenced and the project under test had MVC 3.0 referenced. FWIW answering it here.

Comment: thank you,  this was helpful as i forget Sitefinity < 6.1 uses MVC 3 not 4!